# Can I detect that a method has been overridden?

Tags: ruby

Suppose here's some arbitrary library code that I don't know about:

```
class Foo
  def hi
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  def hi
  end
end
```

And suppose I have some code where I'm passed `Bar` as a parameter.

```
def check(x)
  do_something_with(x.method(:hi))
end
```

In the above example, can I know that `x.hi` (where `x` references an instance of `Bar`) is different from `Foo#hi`?

---

Based on Gareth's answer, this is what I've got so far:

```
def is_overridden?(method)
  name = method.name.to_sym
  return false if !method.owner.superclass.method_defined?(name)
  method.owner != method.owner.superclass.instance_method(name).owner
end
```

Hideous? Gorgeous?

Comment: While it's not necessarily relevant, I'm curious as to why you want to do this.

Comment: Also, it appears you only care about "overriding" with respect to inheritance as opposed to redefining an existing method on the same class?

Answer (score 14):

You could do this:

```
if x.method(:hi).owner == Foo
```

I am far from being a Ruby expert; I will not be surprised if someone has a better way than this.

Comment: Nice! Just stumbled across the same thing myself. And—like you—I will wait to see if someone else comes along and shoots us down for this approach. If not, I'll accept this as I think I can use it to achieve what I'm after.

Comment: @DanTao It may not matter in your case, but if `Foo` is monkey-patched, it'll still report `Foo` is the owner.

Comment: I don't really see how it could do anything else in that case. (And monkey-patching isn't *overriding* anyway.) Am I missing something?

Comment: @DaveNewton: Fortunately not applicable in my case, but good to point out—thanks.

Comment: This is what I would suggest. But based on the question, you should maybe reconsider your approach. If you need to know the sources of the methods, then you might be violating the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) you definitely don't want this code to have to know about all the different things that could be subclassing, and what to do for each of them. Avdi described this idea as a choose your own adventure book, where the page says "if you came from page 19, then ..., if you came from page 84, then ...".

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question! I wondered about the same question. You can reopen Bar class and check who are the ancestors in the lookup path of Bar that have the method defined.

```
class Bar < Foo
  ancestors.each do |ancestor|
    puts ancestor if ancestor.instance_methods.include?(:hi)
  end
end
```